# Select "Sent Items" on Outlook with Keyboard Maestro

Tags: ms-office, keybindings

Is there any way to have Keyboard Maestro select "Sent Items" on an app like Microsoft Outlook upon pressing a hot key?

I have tried with "Select Menu" and "Press Button" but none of these options seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

## Selecting Intractable GUI Elements with Keyboard Maestro

This is one of the most useful aspects of Keyboard Maestro, the ability to manipulate a GUI which is not easily accessed by other scripting options. I'll explain how to use this routine to solve your question, but it can be used for just about anything else.

The recycable core of the method is a sequence of three **actions**:

1. `Find Image on Screen`.
2. `Use Variable` in the `to set the mouse location` mode.
3. `Move or Click Mouse` relative to the `current mouse location`.

Once these three **actions** are dragged into your macro, you'll need to configure them slightly:

1. Take a screenshot of the graphical element you would like to select using **⌘-⇧-4**.
2. Drag the screenshot into the `Find Image on Screen` box.
3. Test it by hitting try with the `Display` box checked while the icon is on the screen.
4. Make sure the same Variable is both set by `Find Image on Screen` and used by `Use Variable`.
5. Adjust the → and ↓ distance so that the button is pressed, in case the image found is slightly larger than the hitbox.

And there you have it. This little block of **actions** is completely modular, so try to think of other fun uses. Here's my final macro:

[image: Select Sent Items Macro]